# considerations about little endian processor and opeartions on registers

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, addressing

Processor is little-endian.
Under followings addresses we have following values (hexdecimal format):

```
1000: FA 
1001: 46 
1002: 26
1003: C3
```

Now, processor is going to do following `16-bits` operations:
1. Load to register `R1` value of address `1000` (remember that operations are `16-bits`).
2.  XOR value of address `1002` with value of register `R1`.
3. Save result of XOR at address `1010`

I show you, how I understand what processor do:
1.  Because of the fact that processor is little-endian it loads to `R1` value:  `46 FA`.
2. xor with value of address `1002` with `R1` is:
`XOR(C3 26, 46 FA)=85 DC`
3. Now, at addresses `1010` and `1011` we have:
`1010:DC`
`1011:85`

Tell me please, Am I ok ? If I correctly understand this issue ?

Comment: Yea you've got it. Just remember little-endian means the memory address points at the least significant byte (the little end), of multi-byte values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it completely correct, and Transistor's answer is good. Here is some extra information though:

Note that logical operations like `XOR`, `AND` and `OR` only look at the same bits in the two values. So in this case it doesn't matter if the processor is little-endian, big-endian, or which way around the operands are. The result will be the same values at addresses `1010` and `1011` regardless:

```
Little Endian:
C326 xor 46FA = 85DC (stored as DC 85)
46FA xor C326 = 85DC (stored as DC 85)
Big Endian:
26C3 xor FA46 = DC85 (stored as DC 85)
FA46 xor 26C3 = DC85 (stored at DC 85)
```

It is only when you use mathematical operations instead of logical ones, like `ADD`, `SUB` and `MUL`, that little-endian and big-endian matter - and in the case of `SUB`, the order of the operands. An `ADD` adds the lowest bits of the two words, which may produce a carry. It then adds the next lowest bits of the two words *plus any carry*, which may produce another carry. This moves up the bits, and so where the byte boundary is becomes important - the carry has to move across it!

```
Little Endian:
C326 + 46FA = 0A20 (stored as 20 0A)
46FA + C326 = 0A20 (stored as 20 0A)
Big Endian:
26C3 + FA46 = 2109 (stored as 21 09)
FA46 + 26C3 = 2109 (stored as 21 09)

Little Endian:
C326 - 46FA = 7C2C (stored as 2C 7C)
46FA - C326 = 83D4 (stored as D4 83)
Big Endian:
26C3 - FA46 = 2C5F (stored as 2C 5F)
FA46 - 26C3 = D383 (stored as D3 83)
```

Comment: thanks you very much!  However I have another one question:  (assuming littler-endian processor, `16`-bits operations, value under address of memory `1000:5D, 1001:AF`)  Then processor loads value of address `1000` into register `R1`.  Then value of `R1` is `AF 5D` .  Ok ?

Comment: Yes. That is 100% correct.

Comment: So during loading value from memory to register, little-endian processor reverse bytes. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your understanding of the "endian" layout ...

[image] [image]

*Figure 1. Little-endian and big-endian memory layout. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).*

... and your calculations are correct.

If anyone wants to check then switch your computer's calculator into *Programmer Mode* and do the hexadecimal XOR calculation.

Comment: On the whole, reasoning is ok ?

Comment: It looks fine. I recommend you un-accept for a day or so to encourage other answers. I don't expect anyone to contradict us but someone may have a tip or a different viewpoint that is helpful in some other way.

Comment: ok, I unaccepted.

Comment: Darn! You got a better answer. ;^) No problem.